# Kivy root widget loading before app error

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Still new to programming, but I'm getting an error that I can find online. What there is online, says to write my .kv code inside my .py file as a string. I don't want to do that.

My Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from database import DataBase
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
import os
from kivy.resources import resource_add_path


ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
resource_add_path(ROOT)


sm = WindowManager()
db = DataBase("users.txt")

screens = [LoginWindow(name="login"), CreateAccountWindow(name="create"),MainWindow(name="main"), Calendar(name="Calendar")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "login"

class MyMainApp(MDApp):

    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"

    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Builder.load_file(os.path.join(ROOT, "my.kv"))
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        App.__init__(self)   


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

My Error:

```
ValueError: KivyMD: App object must be initialized before loading root widget.
```

Comment: Hi there! You'd make it easier to answer your question if you make sure you're posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In particular, you didn't import `WindowManager()` anywhere, so it throws an error, and we don't have (or probably need) your `database` code. Also you should probably provide a (minimal) `my.kv` example, and remove any code that you can remove and still get the error.

Comment: P.S. This isn't directly related to your question, but Python's [Pathlib](https://treyhunner.com/2018/12/why-you-should-be-using-pathlib/) is excellent, and can make code way more readable and convenient than all the `os.path.join` stuff. For instance, you could do `ROOT = Path(__file__).resolve().parent`, which might not seem much better, but then you can refer to a file in that folder as simply `ROOT / 'my.kv'` and it just works, regardless of what OS you're on.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write an `__init__()` method for your `App`. Remove the `__init__()` method and add a `build()` method:

```
class MyMainApp(MDApp):

    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file(os.path.join(ROOT, "my.kv"))
```

This assumes that your `kv` file defines a root widget.